A Problem with two programmers working on a program, one after another
Problem:
A and B are two computer programmers. They need to write a program. Either one could complete the program in 10 hours working alone. Unfortunately, they only have 1 computer available, so only one person can work at a time.
A starts out at their maximum work rate, but gets tired, so their work rate decreases linearly to a minimum of 10% of maximum after 10 hours. B's work rate starts at zero and increases linearly to their maximum at 10 hours. At the point where A's work rate is the same as B's work rate, A stops working and B takes over.  Assuming the clock starts for both A and B at the same time, how many hours will B have to work to complete the program?
Answer:
The first step is to find when B takes over. Call that point $t_s$.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{10} - 0.01*t_s &= 0.01*t_s \\
\dfrac{1}{10} &= \dfrac{t_s}{50} \\
t_s &= 5 \\
\end{align*}
That means that after $5$ hours, A will step down and B will take over. Let
$w_s$ be the fraction of work completed at that point.
\begin{align*}
w_s &= \dfrac{ \int_0^5 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} \, \mathrm{d}t }
 { \int_0^9 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} \, \mathrm{d}t  + 0.1 } \\
\int_0^5 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} \, \mathrm{d}t &= t - \dfrac{t^2}{200} \bigg|_{0}^{5} \\
\int_0^5 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} \, \mathrm{d}t &= 5 - \dfrac{5^2}{200} - ( 0 ) \\
\int_0^5 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} \, \mathrm{d}t &= 5 - \dfrac{1}{8}  \\
\int_0^5 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} \, \mathrm{d}t &= \dfrac{ 39}{8} \\
\int_0^9 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} &= t - \dfrac{t^2}{200} \bigg|_{0}^{9} \\
\int_0^9 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} &= 9 - \dfrac{81}{200} \\
\int_0^9 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} &= \dfrac{1800 - 81}{200} \\
\int_0^9 1 - \dfrac{t}{100} &= \dfrac{1719}{200} \\
w_s &= \dfrac{   \dfrac{ 39}{8} } { \dfrac{1719}{200} + .1  } \\
w_s &= \dfrac{   \dfrac{ 39}{8} } { \dfrac{1719}{200} + \dfrac{20}{200}  } \\
w_s &= \dfrac{   \dfrac{ 39}{8} } { \dfrac{1739}{200}  } \\
\end{align*}
Now we simplify the fraction.
\begin{align*}
w_s &= \dfrac{ 39}{8}  \left( \dfrac{200}{1739}  \right) = \dfrac{ 39(25)} {1739}\\
w_s &= \dfrac{ 975 }{1739} \\
w_s &\doteq 0.5606671
\end{align*}
However, the book says at the point that B takes over, the problem is
$70.45\%$ complete. Where did I go wrong?

I'm not sure how you hope to find $t_s$ first. I would first write equations describing the two work rates as functions of time, with parameters for the two unknown maximum work rates, and then solve for the parameters using the fact that either programmer could complete the job in 10 hours. After that, you can find the point where the graphs intersect.

@Karl I found $t_s$ to be $5$. I have been told that is correct.

Are you saying that Greg's work rate is $w(t)=\frac{1}{10}-0.01t$?  That would mean $w(10)=0$, but Greg should still be functioning at 10% capacity at this point.

@tabstop I am saying that Greg's work is :  $w(t) = \max( 1/10,  \dfrac{1}{10} - 0.01t)$.

@Bob okay -- but even with that you have that $w(9)$ also equals 10% capacity, which doesn't match the specifications either -- I read those specs as saying that Greg should first reach 10% capacity at ten hours, i.e. he should be losing .009 per hour rather than .01 (since he needs to decrease from 0.1 to 0.01 in ten hours).

@Bob although then you have the other part of the issue: does Greg need 10 hours at max capacity to finish the program (in which case we can safely use 0.1 as his max work rate), or will he finish the program in ten hours in this Greg-gets-tired paradigm, in which case you would need to write Greg's work rate as $k(1-.09t)$ and find a $k$ such that the integral from 0 to 10 of $w(t)$ would get you 1 fully solved problem.

So, I will step in and confirm that you are right to find $t_s$ to be $5$. I'm not sure I follow your rationale, but I feel the framing I used to solve the problem up until finding $w_s$ might clarify matters and leads to the expected answer, so I'll start from the beginning...

Notation:
First, some notation I'll be using that is slightly different from yours. I will define the following variables and functions:

$\newcommand{\B}{W_{\text{Bob}}}
\newcommand{\G}{W_{\text{Greg}}}
\newcommand{\t}{t_{\text{swap}}}
\newcommand{\w}{w_{\text{swap}}}
\newcommand{\g}{r_{\text{Greg}}}
\newcommand{\b}{r_{\text{Bob}}}
\newcommand{\M}{M_{\text{Greg}}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\G(x)$ represents Greg's work rate, and $\B(x)$ Bob's, in terms of $x$ hours.
$\g$ is the rate at which Greg's work rate changes, and $\b$ is Bob's.
$\M$ is Greg's maximum work rate from which he declines.
$\t$ is the time of the swap in question, which you label $t_s$.
$\w$ is the work done up to the time in question, which you label $w_s$.


The Form of the Workers' Functions:
So, at the immediate outset, we can deduce the following:

$\G(x),\B(x)$ are linear functions.
We will assume without loss of generality that $\g,\b > 0$.
We note that since Bob starts at zero, we have $\B(0) = 0$.
Meanwhile $\G(x) = \frac{\M}{10}$ for $x > 10$.
Bob stays at his maximum work rate beyond the ten hours, so $\B(x) = 10 \b$ for $x > 10$.
Naturally, $\G(x),\B(x)$ should be continuous functions since Greg and Bob don't take sharp sudden changes in work rate. This becomes useful later.

So, we know right now that
$$\begin{align*}
\G(x) &= \begin{cases}
\M - \g \cdot x, & 0 \le x < 10 \\
0.1 \cdot \M, & x \ge 10
\end{cases} \\
\B(x) &= \begin{cases}
\b \cdot x, & 0 \le x < 10 \\
10 \cdot \b, & x \ge 10
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Finding Unknown Constants: Bob's Rate of Change $\b$:
Our next task becomes deducing the constants $\M,\g,\b$. This is where the condition that each programmer can do the work in $10$ hours comes in: this means
$$
\frac{1}{10} \int_0^{10} \G(x) \, \dd x
= \frac{1}{10} \int_0^{10} \B(x) \, \dd x
= 1
$$
Why this setup? Well, we know $10$ hours is spent programming, and the average rate of work will be given by $\frac{1}{10} \int_0^{10} W(x) \, \dd x$ for each worker. More generally, this is the definition of the average value of an integrable function $f$:
$$
\text{average value of $f$ over $(a,b)$}
=
\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) \, \dd x
$$
We equate the two integrals to $1$ ($100\%$) to show a completed project.
A natural question may be "why integrals:" we are summing up incredibly small changes in the work rate, to get incredibly small contributions to the work done. (Think of how Riemann sums sum up across incredibly small changes in a function to get a very small rectangle that contributes to the overall area under a curve. This too becomes an important detail and thus clarifies how I calculate $\w$!)
Naturally, then,
$$
 \int_0^{10} \G(x) \, \dd x
=   \int_0^{10} \B(x) \, \dd x
= 10
$$
(This can perhaps be deduced more directly, since the integral represents the sum of their contributions to the work, and $10$ can be interpreted as $10$ hours of work.)
Substitute in our equations. First, Bob's is easier so we begin there:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{10} \B(x) \, \dd x
&= \int_0^{10} \b x \, \dd x \\
&= \b \int_0^{10} x \, \dd x \\
&= \frac{\b}{2}  x^2 \bigg|_0^{10}  \\
&= 50 \b 
\end{align*}$$
But if this needs to equal $10$, then
$$
50 \b = 10 
\implies
\b = \frac{1}{5}
$$
and hence
$$\B(x) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac 1 5 x, & 0 \le x < 10 \\
2, & x \ge 10
\end{cases} $$

Finding Unknown Constants: Greg's Maximum Rate $\M$:
Before we do the same with Greg's work function, we note that self-imposed continuity condition. Again recall that
$$
\G(x) = \begin{cases}
\M - \g \cdot x, & 0 \le x < 10 \\
0.1 \cdot \M, & x \ge 10
\end{cases} 
$$
For this to be continuous, since for $x \in (0,10)$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$ we have polynomial functions, we clearly just need
$$
\lim_{x \to 10^+} \G(x) = \lim_{x \to 10^-} \G(x) = \G(10)
$$
and need to figure out how to define $\M$ or $\g$ appropriately to ensure this. Well, given the simplicity of our situation (the continuity of the function on each branch), taking those limits just amounts to plugging in $10$; we will need
$$
\underbrace{\lim_{x \to 10^+} \G(x)
= \frac{\M}{10}}_{\text{right branch}}
= \underbrace{\M - \g \cdot x
= \lim_{x \to 10^-} \G(x)}_{\text{left branch}}
$$
We can't solve for all of our constants, but since $\g$ appears only in one side of the equation we can solve for $\M$ in terms of it thankfully. Rearrange the equation and we can conclude
$$
\M = \frac{100}{9} \g
$$
Hence, with a little simplifying,
$$
\G(x) = \begin{cases}
 \displaystyle \g \left( \frac{100}{9}  -  x \right), & 0 \le x < 10 \\
 \displaystyle \frac{10}{9} \g, & x \ge 10
\end{cases} 
$$

Finding Unknown Constants: Greg's Rate of Change $\g$:
Now we can perform the same analysis as we did earlier for Bob:
$$\begin{align*}
10
= \int_0^{10} \G(x) \, \dd x 
&= \int_0^{10} \g \left( \frac{100}{9}  -  x \right) \, \dd x \\
&= \frac{100\g}{9} \int_0^{10} \, \dd x - \g \int_0^{10} x \, \dd x \\
&= \frac{100\g}{9} x \bigg|_0^{10} - \frac{\g}{2} x^2 \bigg|_0^{10} \\
&= \frac{1000\g}{9}  - \frac{100\g}{2}  \\
&=\g \left( \frac{1000}{9}  - \frac{100}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{550}{9} \g
\end{align*}$$
And, as before, since this must equal $10$,
$$
\frac{550}{9} \g = 10
\implies
\g = \frac{9}{55}
$$
and hence, again with some simplifying,
$$
\G(x) = \begin{cases}
 \displaystyle \frac{20}{11}  - \frac{9}{55} x , & 0 \le x < 10 \\
 \displaystyle \frac{5}{11}, & x \ge 10
\end{cases} 
$$

Aside: Graphs:
Since visuals are often nice, I figured I'd graph these in Desmos (especially since I was lazily fiddling with Desmos already to figure out the problem and check my work).
Here's the demo.
Below, we have $\color{green}{\G(x) }$  in green and $\color{blue}{\B(x) }$ in blue:


Finding the Time of Swap, $\t$:
So, at long last, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\G(x) &= \begin{cases}
 \displaystyle \frac{20}{11}  - \frac{9}{55} x , & 0 \le x < 10 \\
 \displaystyle \frac{5}{11}, & x \ge 10
\end{cases} \\
\B(x) &= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac 1 5 x, & 0 \le x < 10 \\
2, & x \ge 10
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
Finding the intersection of these lines is the same as ever, as in your algebra classes. The framing of the problem implies an intersection in $[0,10]$, so we just focus on equating those branches:
$$
\frac 1 5 x
= 
\frac{20}{11}  - \frac{9}{55} x
\implies
x=5
$$
Since the time of the swap $\t$ is meant to be when $\G(\t) = \B(\t)$, we thus conclude
$$
\t = 5
$$

The Amount Of Work Done, $\w$:
At long last, we get to what your question actually was about in the first place: how much work $\w$ was done at the time of the swap $\t$? Well, we established earlier that
$$
 \int_0^t \G(x) \, \dd x
$$
represents the work done by Greg on the project in the time interval $[0,t]$. The proportion of work completed would naturally be, since it would take him $10$ hours to complete, would be
$$
\frac{\displaystyle \int_0^t \G(x) \, \dd x}{\displaystyle \int_0^{10} \G(x) \, \dd x}
= \frac{1}{10} \int_0^t \G(x) \, \dd x 
$$
and hence, at the time of the swap,
$$
\w = \frac{1}{10} \int_0^{\t} \G(x) \, \dd x
= \frac{1}{10} \int_0^5 \G(x) \, \dd x
$$
A natural calculation follows:
$$\begin{align*}
\w
&= \frac{1}{10} \int_0^{5} \left( \frac{20}{11}  - \frac{9}{55} x \right) \, \dd x \\ 
&= \frac{2}{11} \int_0^5 \, \dd x - \frac{9}{550} \int_0^5 x \, \dd x \\
&= \frac{2}{11} x \bigg|_0^5 - \frac{9}{1100} x^2 \bigg|_0^5 \\
&= \frac{10}{11}  - \frac{9 \cdot 25}{1100} \\
&= \frac{31}{44}\\
&= 0.70\overline{45}
\end{align*}$$
Recalling we worked in decimals the whole time, this justifies the claimed answer.
